# C : poll function limit

Tags: c, function, limits

When I use the poll function and set the quantity above 1000 it does not sleep at all. Any ideas of what this could be. opengroup says nothing about a limit and I am no where near exhausting my memory space. But when I check the pointer the integer is negative. Any ideas of what this could be?

Comment: What was the return value from `poll`? If it was -1, what was the value of `errno`?

Comment: perror("poll"); = poll: Invalid argument

Comment: Was looking for what function to use from errno.h but i couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that your limit for file descriptors is set to 1024. You can see this by running `ulimit -n` in *bash* (unix). For windows see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/111855. If you are running linux, you can increase that limit by modifying /etc/limits.conf (or /etc/security/limits.conf or similar) like:

```
*               soft    nofile  10240
*               hard    nofile  10240
```

Note that after changing the limits you will have to log out and log back in for it to have the new values.

Comment: I have been wondering the limit all while I have been making this. Now is there a max for this number? What are the dependencies why it was set so low by default?

Comment: @Jay, the maximum value that you can set for `nofile` rlimits is controllable via `/proc/sys/fs/file-max`; see the `proc(5)` entry.

Comment: You can get the maximum value in many different ways. getdtablesize() and getrlimit() with RLIMIT_NOFILE... 1024 open fds is a lot for a typical application. For servers, you usually know what you're doing and you increase this value to whatever fits your needs.

Comment: The odd thing is I don't see a rule set already as if it just defaults to 1024 without the need for it.

Answer (score 1):

If `poll()` returns a negative number, you should use `perror("poll");` to show the reason.

If the reason is "Invalid Argument", it could be for this reason (from [the Linux `poll()` man page](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/poll.2.html)):

> `EINVAL`
>
> The *nfds* value exceeds the
>   `RLIMIT_NOFILE` value.

By the way, the POSIX spec lists this as an error too:

> The poll() function shall fail if: 
>   ...  `[EINVAL]`
>       The `nfds` argument is greater than `{OPEN_MAX}`